# g++ string remove_if error

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio-2010, g++, remove-if

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string word="";
    getline(cin,word);
    word.erase(remove_if(word.begin(), word.end(), isspace), word.end()); 
    word.erase(remove_if(word.begin(), word.end(), ispunct), word.end()); 
    word.erase(remove_if(word.begin(), word.end(), isdigit), word.end());
}
```

When compiled in VS 2010, it works perfectly fine. Compiled with G++ it says:

```
hw4pr3.cpp: In function `int main()':
hw4pr3.cpp:20: error: no matching function for call to `remove_if(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, <unknown type>)'
hw4pr3.cpp:21: error: no matching function for call to `remove_if(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, <unknown type>)'
hw4pr3.cpp:22: error: no matching function for call to `remove_if(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, <unknown type>)'
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Add `::` to the beginning of `isspace`, `ispunct` and `isdigit`, since they have overloads that the compiler can't decide on which to use:

```
word.erase(remove_if(word.begin(), word.end(), ::isspace), word.end()); 
word.erase(remove_if(word.begin(), word.end(), ::ispunct), word.end()); 
word.erase(remove_if(word.begin(), word.end(), ::isdigit), word.end());
```

Comment: At best having C library functions in the global namespace is deprecated and legacy (you would have to include `<ctype.h>`), and at worst its just an odd compiler peculiarity that shouldn't be relied upon.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I didn't realise it was deprecated/hacky, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 4):

Add `#include <cctype>` (and say `std::isspace` etc. if you aren't `abusing namespace std;`).

Always include all headers that you need, and don't rely on hidden nested inclusions.

You may also have to disambiguate the overload from the other one in `<locale>`. Do this by adding an explicit cast:

```
word.erase(std::remove_if(word.begin(), word.end(),
                          static_cast<int(&)(int)>(std::isspace)),
           word.end());
```

Answer (score 2):

For me it compiles using g++ if I do either of the following:

- remove `using namespace std;` and change `string` to `std::string`; or
- change `isspace` to `::isspace` (etc.).

Either of these will cause `isspace` (etc.) to be taken from the main namespace, instead of being interpreted as possibly meaning `std::isspace` (etc.).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that std::isspace(int) takes an int as a parameter but a string is composed of char. So you have to write your own function as:

> bool isspace(char c) { return c == ' '; }

The same applies to the other two functions.